# NG8001: 'mat-label' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular-material

Even though I have already imported these 3 modules ( `FormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, BrowserModule,`) The error is appearing.

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {MatFormField, MatFormFieldModule, MatLabel} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogComponent,
 
   
  ],
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatLabel
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Error:

Error: src/app/dialog/dialog.component.html:36:9 - error
NG8001: 'mat-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
36         Comment

Comment: How did you imported them?

Comment: I will edit the code with imports.please have a look on it.

Comment: Ok I will try @AndrewAllen

Comment: I tried @AndrewAllen But there is nothing called MatLabelModule. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74968344/16349670 here this is another issue, could you please give me support? I'm still struggling

Comment: @NimashaMadhushani sorry, not thinking properly, you're right but no need to import MatLabel. Behram's answer should work. Please provide minimal reproducible example that gives the error

Comment: @AndrewAllen thank you for the support I solved the problem. I will add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try like below example:

```
 import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DialogComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried with schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] also

Comment: I just replace my whole code with yours. then it's working properly. thank you @Behram

Answer (score 1):

With this module you also be require 'MatInputModule' to be imported.

you can check below sample module for reference:

```
// common-widgets.module.ts
 import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
 import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule
  ]
  })
  export class CommonWidgetsModule { }
```

Comment: please have a look at the edited question. I have already imported modules correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here I went through the @Behram s answer and fixed my issue. DialogComponent is customized component implement by me and need to import the path here to declare the component in declerations.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}
```